# Why canvasTexture in Three.js display so small?

Tags: three.js

#### I add a canvas textue for THREE.Sprite like this:

```
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 320
    canvas.height = 320

    const colors = {
        border: '#3c3443',
        top: '#9d94a7',
        bottom: '#796e8c'
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = colors.border;
    ctx.fillStyle = colors.bottom;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 320);

    const canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

    const spriteMaterail = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        map: canvasTexture,
        color: 0xffffff
    });
    const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterail);
    sprite.position.y = 40;
    this.scene.add(sprite);
```

#### but it finally display like this:

[image]

#### How can set the size properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sprite.scale.set(30,30,30); //This sets the sprite scale to 30 on all axis.
```

or:

```
sprite.scale.multiplyScalar(30); //This multiplies the scale by 30
```

Just be careful not to set 0 scales anywhere, or you may get warnings about non-invertible matrices, due to a three.js optimization that requires a minimum scale value.